# How to configure Visual Studio Code to build and debug STM32 projects using STM32CubeMX - Windows 10

Tags: stm32, visual-studio-code, microcontroller, cubemx

I am new to the realm of STM32 programming and have been trying to find a suitable IDE for quite a while now. I know of all the other IDEs, like [Keil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keil_(company)) and [IAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAR_Systems#IAR_Embedded_Workbench), but the cost of buying them just to learn is far too steep for me at this point in time.

I have started using Visual Studio Code for a growing amount of my development work and I thought it would be a good IDE to use for STM32 development. I have found many examples online over the past few days on how to configure the IDE to build STM32 projects, but they all seem to be missing important information that I need to properly get the project to compile. It is rather frustrating,

Is there a complete setup guide on how to set up Visual Studio Code to work with STM32CubeMX and the ARM toolchain? Or is there a sample project that I can use as a base learn from?

Just some background information, I know how to use STM32CubeMX to generate the base project as well as the associated makefile, I also have the latest GNU-Tools-Arm-Embedded installed.

Comment: While I don't have details regarding VS Code in conjunction with STM32, have you thought of Atollic TrueSTUDIO? It's based on Eclipse, actively supported by ST and CubeMX should generate ready projects for it. And most importantly - it's free.

Comment: I have not heard of this, I will definitely check this option out as well then, thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? What was not working? I don't use VS Code, but setting compiler to gcc-arm-none-eabi, pointing include and source dirs with CMSIS, HAL, and LL, and defining linker script should be enough. [Here](https://github.com/ObKo/stm32-cmake) is a CMake based version I use in Emacs.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, and I like VSC a lot but for this purpose, a free package that works just out of the box is SW4STM32: https://www.openstm32.org/HomePage. In the cubeMX set the toolchain for it and it just compiles easy. Also has a strong debugging tool, trust me you gonna need them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A while ago I had the same question, but I did not find anything that I really liked. So I created [STM32 for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmd.stm32-for-vscode). It is an extension for Visual Studio Code which works with STM32CubeMX-generated files and sets up building and debugging for you.

Comment: I tried this extension, however it did not work. Seems that toolchain installation fails.

Comment: @CreekDrop the automatic toolchain installation didn't work for me either, but installing GNUWin, OpenOCD and the arm toolchain manually and adding them to PATH made the extension start properly.

Answer (score 11):

1. Install [GNU Arm Embedded toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) and add its bin folder to your PATH environment variable.
2. You will also need a `make` to execute your makefiles, so download [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). The easiest way is to download the binaries and extract it somewhere on your system. Add it (`C:\make-3.81-bin\bin`) to your PATH as well.
3. Create an STM32CubeMX project and select `Makefile` as Toolchain/IDE.

   [image]
4. At this point, you will be able to build the generated project by simply using `make` in the project's root folder.
5. If you open the project in Visual Studio Code, you can build using its terminal or you can create a Visual Studio Code task to execute the `make` command. You can bind your task to a hotkey as well to spare some time.
6. To debug, the easiest way is to install [Cortex-Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug) Visual Studio Code extension. Follow [the instructions](https://marcelball.ca/projects/cortex-debug/) to configure your debug sessions.

Comment: This comment was also a large help thank you, this in combination with the answer that I checked makes up the full solution. I just can check both off.

Comment: @clixxclixx That is alright. What important is that you could solve it and came back to accept an answer after more than 3 years. Not many do that. :)
Your question was a great hit anyway with more than 30k views, great contribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library of Python scripts that does just this. It has been released recently with excellent documentation and after testing I can say it works as advertised.

[Visual Studio Code STM32 IDE](https://github.com/damogranlabs/VS-Code-STM32-IDE)

The process is quite straightforward:

1. Export the files using [STM32CubeMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Cortex-M)
2. Open the Visual Studio Code folder and save it as a workspace
3. Copy the scripts `"ideScripts" directory` to your project folder
4. Run *update.py*

Here is a video on how it works:

[Visual Studio Code STM32 IDE - Getting Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWjb43kLHdQ)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a very good [answer by Bence Kaulics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391938/how-to-configure-visual-studio-code-to-build-and-debug-stm32-projects-using-stm3/51427443#51427443). Based on it,
I add my recent findings.

5. The `make` command somehow did not work for me in Visual Studio Code Terminal. To solve this, I installed "Makefile Tools" extension from Microsoft.
6. The instruction link does not work, and therefore I add steps how to configure debugging for [J-Link](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/).

   Install the Cortex-Debug extension. Download and install the J-Link software from [Segger](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/). Get the [SVD file](https://github.com/posborne/cmsis-svd/tree/master/data/STMicro) if you want to see peripheral registers. Edit the *launch.json* file (see the code below). Set your executable, paths and device.

   ```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "executable": "./build/STM32F103RBT6_Test1.elf",
                "name": "Debug Microcontroller",
                "request": "launch",
                "type": "cortex-debug",
                "servertype": "jlink",
                "serverpath": "C:/Program Files/SEGGER/JLink/JLinkGDBServerCL.exe",
                "armToolchainPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/10 2021.10/bin",
                "device": "STM32F103RB",
                "interface": "swd",
                //"serialNumber": "", // If multiple debuggers attached
                "runToMain": true,
                "svdFile": "${workspaceRoot}/device/STM32F103xx.svd",
            }
        ]
    }
   ```