# How to Erase and Flash STM32 in VS Code using J-Link

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm32, microcontroller, segger-jlink

I have set up VS Code to build and debug STM32 using instructions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51391938/7004375). Everything works fine, I can run and debug code. However I would like to just flash or erase target without starting debug session. I am using J-Link debugger. What would be the most convenient way to perform these actions?

Comment: use j-flash program. You do not need VS code for that

Comment: Thanks for tip. J-Flash does not work with my debugger, however J-Flash Lite does the job.